# How to check for dynamic mongoid attribute in embedded model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I need a clean way to check for the existence of a dynamic attribute on an embedded Mongoid model instance.

This works for a top level model;

```
account.attributes.member?("coordinates")
```

But my coordinates are stored in an embedded model, locations.  The following throws an undefined method error;

```
account.locations.attributes.member?("coordinates")
```

Anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Because it seems the locations is an array of embedded documents. probably has many relationship.

There is no method name `attributes` for an data type `array`. Thats why you are getting the undefined error.  You can fix that by

```
  account.locations[0].attributes.member?("coordinates")
```

or check the coordinates member in whole array using

```
  account.locations.map {|x| [x.id,x.attributes.member? 'coordinates'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following because I can't even depend on the locations attribute being there;

if @account.locations? 
  if !@account.locations[0].coordinates? 
    if @account.locations[0].coordinates.blank? 
      #do something 
    end 
  end
end

Kind of messy but it works.
Thanks for the response Ramesh!

note, for some reason I cant get the code formatting to work...  sorry